# Auto pause/resume in backgrounddownloader if DownloadOperation.Progress.Status PausedNoNetwork

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, download

How I can use Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundDownloader for auto pause/resume downloading big files if lost connection to the network?

I'm trying to download big file with Windows BackgroundDownloader:

```
var userFolder = await GetUserFolder();
var file = await userFolder.CreateFileAsync("BigFile.iso", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

var backgroundDownloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
_downloadOperation = backgroundDownloader.CreateDownload(new Uri("http://mirrors.melbourne.co.uk/ubuntu-releases//raring/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso"), file);

var progress = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(operation =>
                {
                    //...Error operation.Progress status if lost connection
                });                

await _downloadOperation.StartAsync().AsTask(new CancellationToken(), progress);
```

Now, if I manually off network adapter, I have DownloadOperation in Progress handler with status PauseNoNetwork:
[image]

And then:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the background transfer API is automatically resilient to changes in connectivity, and will pause an operation if connectivity is lost and automatically resume it later. It's also resilient to roaming between networks, picking the one with the best cost model, and so on.

In your case I suspect that you're hitting a timeout, and so the progress handler reports and error vs. a pause. The key here is that the error is reported in the *Progress* handler; you should also have a *Completed* handler to tell you when the operation as a whole--rather that just progress--has completed or failed. That is, if the Completed handler has not yet been called, then the operation is still active even through Progress got an error, and should in fact, restart.

Try checking the DownloadOperation.Progress property (a [BackgroundDownloadProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloadprogress.aspx) value) to see if indicates HasRestarted.